# These were just lying around

Tags: wordplay, pattern

What peculiar property do all these words have in common?

```
AMP

APP

BARF

COME

CUR

EAR

GANG

GROW

IMP

ON

PEAR

PIMP

SING

STAB

TRIP
```

---

**Afterword:**

> As @TwoBitOperation astutely observed, it's not just that you can add –LY to each of these words to get a new word.  It's that the new word is etymologically distinct from the original word.  The original word is not the stem/base of the new word, and sometimes it even changes pronunciation upon adding –LY.
>
>   It actually took a fair amount of deep dictionary research to be sure.  For example, I didn't realize that HARDLY really does come from HARD, and HOMELY really does come from HOME.  I'm still not sure about PORT/PORTLY, as I found the etymologies confusing.
>
>   A few others that didn't make the shortlist:
>
>   COMP
>
>   CRAW
>
>   DANG
>
>   FEE
>
>   REP

Comment: Inspired by a puzzle posted by @HughMeyers

Comment: Woo! I'd present, like, hard rep! (as a reward for creating this clever puzzle, were it not for the time limit on bounties.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For each given word you can:

> Add **LY** to get a new word.

This is hinted at by:

> The title suggesting 'LY-ing'

Edit:

> I was reading 'BARFLY' wrong which lead to some doubt.  Clever!

Double edit :

> And it's worth noting that none of the new words are just adverb forms of the original. Double clever!

Comment: Nice! The title fits as well :)

Comment: @jafe: Indeed, it's only LY-ing, it's also plain *lying* about their origins.